# SolrNet Duplicate File Conents

Tags: solr, solrnet

All,

I wrote a method that extends some of the functionality in the SolrNet example MVC app. It's very simple and in my controller I added the following.

public string Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance>();
                String qs = Request.QueryString["q"];
                var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("asciiname", qs));

```
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            buffer.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
            buffer.Append("<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\"\n");
            buffer.Append(" xmlns:gx=\"http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2\">\n");
            buffer.Append("<Document>\n");
            buffer.Append("<name>\n");
            buffer.Append("Gazetteer\n");
            buffer.Append("</name>\n");
            buffer.Append("<description>\n");
            buffer.Append("World Places\n");
            buffer.Append("</description>\n");

            foreach (var i in results)
            {
                String lat = i.latitude.ToString();
                String lon = i.longitude.ToString();
                String name = i.asciiName.ToString();
                String coords = lon.ToString() + ","  + lat.ToString();

                name = name.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                name = name.Replace("<", "&lt;");
                name = name.Replace(">", "&gt;");

                buffer.Append("<Placemark>\n");
                buffer.Append("<name>\n");
                buffer.Append(name);
                buffer.Append("</name>\n");
                buffer.Append("<Point>\n");
                buffer.Append("<coordinates>\n");
                buffer.Append(coords);
                buffer.Append("</coordinates>\n");
                buffer.Append("</Point>\n");
                buffer.Append("</Placemark>\n");
            }
            buffer.Append("</Document>\n");
            buffer.Append("</kml>");
            Response.Write(buffer.ToString());

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=geonames.kml");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "kml");

            return buffer.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

The KML file is generated but the content is duplicated starting at the  tag. Is this happening in var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance>(); for some reason? I have been walking through the debugger all day and can't seem to figure out why it's writing out the whole thing twice. It does utilize the foreach loop and iterate properly through that but again, it's duplicating the contents of the entire file.

Any help on this would be great!
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Ughhh...I completely overlooked the fact that I was writing the buffer out twice!

```
Response.Write(buffer.ToString());
```

and

```
return buffer.ToString();
```

Adam